# Notepad++ pre-defined search and replaces

Tags: search, macros, replace, notepad++

I need to format a .txt (or CSV) file with a lot of lines.

So I do something like this :

```
 Remove first three lines
 Replace "values" with "i|j|k"
 Remove { and }
 Replace , with |
```

And I need to do this on a lot of files. So doing it manually, I think, is not so time-efficient.

How can I define such an action in Notepad++?

If not possible, any other solution would be ok. Maybe javascript / html file can do this but the files can contain > 10000 rows, so please consider that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the first file.
2. Start recording macro.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> 3 times. Finally press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, and use "Replace All" to change `values` to `i|j|k`.
5. Replace All `{` with empty string.
6. Replace All `}` with empty string.
7. Replace All `,` with `|`.
8. Stop recording macro.
9. Run macro on other files.